# Dynamic data type choosing based on template

Tags: c++, templates

suppose I have an object like this:

```
class Spline {
public:
    Spline(std::size_t const dim);
    // Quite a few functions here. One of those:
    vec operator()(double const t) const; // Returns vector of dimension d
}
```

Now, at most uses of this class, the dimension will already be determined at compile time, thus it would be a good idea (for performance reasons) to change the class like this:

```
template <std::size_t dim>
class Spline {
public:
    Spline();
    // Quite a few functions here. One of those:
    vec::fixed<dim> operator()(double const t) const; // Returns vector of dimension d
}
```

(For those who wonder, `vec` and `vec::fixed` are objects defined by the armadillo linear algebra library). Now I would like to have both versions living in parallel, thus being able to choose the dimension at compile time as well as during runtime. In short, I would like to create the equivalent of `vec::fixed<dim>` as `Spline::fixed<dim>`, but without implementing all functions twice. Especially, I would have to choose the return type of all those functions depending on whether there is a template argument present or not.

Do you have any idea how I might accomplish this, especially thinking in terms of a clear and maintainable design? (In the hope that I made myself clear, which I am not totally sure about.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a simple traits metastruct and specialize that.

```
template<std::size_t dim>
struct spline_return_traits{
  typedef vec::fixed<dim> type;
};

template<>
struct spline_return_traits<0>{ // 0 is a special marker for runtime dimensions
  typedef vec type;
};

template<std::size_t dim>
class Spline_impl{
  typedef typename spline_return_traits<dim>::type spline_return;
public:
  spline_return operator()(double const t) const;
// if <dim> is 0, then the dynamic vec will be chosen as the return type
  // all your functions
};

class Spline : public Spline_impl<0>{ // default is dynamic
public:
  template<int dim>
  struct fixed : public Spline_impl<dim>{
  };
};
```

Now you simple use that. :) Every operator, constructor and function of `Spline_impl` should be available in the subclasses. For the implementation of each function, you need to do some branching where it's a must to decide between runtime or fixed `vec`:

```
if(dim == 0){
  // runtime specific stuff
}else{
  // compile-time specific stuff
}
```

Use as:

```
Spline dynamic_spline;
Spline::fixed<10> fixed_10_spline;
```

Only problem being that the `Spline` class will be double the size of `Spline_impl`... :/ Lemme think if I can find a solution to that too.
**Edit**: If you don't want `Spline` to be double the size of `Spline_impl`, one possibility is to add a little verbosity and a typedef:

```
class Spline : public Spline_impl<0>{ // default is dynamic size
public:
  template<std::size_t dim>
  struct fixed{
    typedef Spline_impl<dim> type;
  };
};
```

And use as

```
Spline dynamic_spline;
typename Spline::fixed<10>::type fixed_10_spline;
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `typename Spline::fixed<10>::type fixed_10_spline;`?

Comment: Thank you. I learn something new every day - this time you made it happen ;)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a `struct` for compile time usage and runtime usage as well with preferably same name. In my opinion, you can declare the `class` as `template` and then specialize one of its instance (say size_t = 0xffffffff), which you may not be using. You can declare all your definitions for runtime usage in that instance.

For example,

```
template<std::size_t dim = ~0> // choose default dimension(0xffffffff) not to be used
class Spline {
public:
  Spline () {}
  vec::fixed<dim> operator () (double const t) const {}
};
template<>
class Spline<~0> {  // specialize the default dimension for runtime use
public:
  Spline (std::size_t const dim) {}
  vec operator () (double const t) const {}
};
```

It can be used as below:

```
Spline<5> o5;  // compile time dimensions
Spline<> o0(3); // run time dimensions (don't mention anything in template)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just overload it. Making a non-duplicate implementation, however, is a problem with no generic solution, unless you have more template magic that can do this.

Comment: Is it possible to overload on return type?